# New to Macs and Automation

Tags: automator

So I am relatively new to Macs and to the Automator program they have. I want to automate a process where I type in a number and that number gets input into a shell script. so something like:

- $num = 20190429.1

and the shell script would have something like:

- MKDIR {filePath}/$num
- CD {filePath}/$num
- {rest of script}

I'm not sure if there is a good tutorial somewhere to show me what I can do with Automator that isn't older than 2017 or that isn't cropping images or audio to text stuff. Can anyone help?

Comment: Also, is it possible to Archive a file in Xcode from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Automator workflow on macOS]

The value entered in the first action (**Ask for Text**) gets sent through to the second action (**Run Shell Script**).  Here, the option for *Pass input* is set to *"as arguments"*; this means that the input is stored in numbered variables `$1`, `$2`, ... and so on, depending on the number of input values.  In this workflow, we only have one input value, so `$1` is the only variable that will contain a value, namely the number entered in the first action.